# Can CALLF (Far Call) has a 64 bit address memory operand in Intel 64 architecture?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, intel

In Intel 32 bit architecture, I can have a call with 32 bit address location using the ModR/M byte. According to Intel Manual, I need to have /2 (010B) for opcode extension, 00B for Mod and 101B allows me to have 32 bit displacement.

If I want to have a far call in 64 bit architecture such that I would have room for 64 bit address, I know I can /3 (011B) for opcode extension. However, still 32 bit displacement is only provided. Is there any way of specifying the target as 64 bit address?

Mainly, I would like to know how can I have a call given the 64 bit address of the location.

Comment: Read Intel's manual: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html.  `call far m16:64`.  And BTW, the target of a far call is a seg:offset, so it's 80 (64+16) or 48 (32+16) bits, not 64.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I do not understand how to use the segment selector. Would you help me more with that? Can you give me the opcode except the address part? Like can you give me a reference of how to assemble the seg, offset and the opcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you asking if `call far [64_bit_absolute]` is encodable?  To fetch the `m16:64` 80-bit operand from a 64-bit absolute address?

**No, [`call far [mem]`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html) isn't special, and ModRM can only do `[disp32]` or `[RIP+rel32]`, or addressing modes involving registers.**  [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes)

Only `mov al/ax/eax/rax, [abs64]` is encodable with a 64-bit absolute address, using a special form of `moffs` MOV that doesn't use a ModRM byte.  This is useless for you: having the segment or offset in a register doesn't help you.

But you can use `mov r64, imm64` to put the address in a register.  e.g.

```
mov  rax, absolute_address      ; where seg:off are stored
call far [rax]
```

Or if your static address is 64-bit, but your assembler + linker know it's in range of the `call` instruction, `call far [rel seg_and_offset]` can use a RIP-relative addressing mode.

---

Otherwise, maybe you're confusing the seg:off call target with location it's stored?  In 64-bit mode, `call ptr16:64` (direct far call) isn't available, so you always need the seg:off in memory for `call` to fetch.  But it can be on the stack or whatever, e.g.

```
push 0x23        ; new CS value ends up in the low 2 bytes of a qword
push rax         ; new offset.  It goes at a lower address because x86 is little-endian
call far [rsp]
```